# Apache SSL vhost won't use DocumentRoot but rather uses server webroot

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2

I have an apache config using a DV wildcard cert. The ssl.conf is configured to use the certificate for all server traffic.

My vhost conf file has two virtual hosts defined there. A production vhost and a dev vhost. The conf file contents are;

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/prod_example_com/

  <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/prod_example_com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/www.example.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/www.example.com-access_log" common

  #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/comodo/STAR_example_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/csr/www_example_com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/comodo/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName dev.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vhosts/dev_example_com"

  <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/dev_example_com">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dev.example.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dev.example.com-access_log" common

  #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/comodo/STAR_example_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/csr/www_example_com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/comodo/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I go to https://dev.example.com, it works great. However, when I try to go to https://www.example.com, it instead goes to the Apache server webroot of /var/www/html.

Have I overlooked something?

Thanks in advance to any help offered?

Comment: I'm beginning to ascertain that this issue has something to do with the <VirtualHost *:443> tag. If I change the dev vhost from <VirtualHost *:443> to <VirtualHost server_ip:443> (where server_ip = to my public IP for the host, then the dev site throws 404 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have found the issue. In my particular instance, the vhost.conf VirtualHost tags were change both to *:443, but what got everything back on track was commenting out ServerName www.example.com:443 from my httpd.conf and restarting Apache. I hope this helps someone else that may be suffering from this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting apache should give you hints in `ssl_error_log`, your first config file suggests you forgot the closing tag `</VirtualHost>`, althought apache should not even start in this case (syntax error).

Comment: Actually, the editor here cut it out. It's in my conf file. I just fixed it in the editor here. Thanks for calling that out though!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Looking in the error log of the VirtualHost, I saw the message:

`client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/www/<virtualhost path>`

This was weird, because I hadn't changed any permissions. Turns out the syntax has changed for Apache 2.4, so make sure to update your permissions if you are updating the server version!

See: [https://www.budgetvm.com/kb/client-denied-by-server-configuration/#:~:text=To%20fix%20%E2%80%9Cclient%20denied%20by,replaced%20by%20%E2%80%9CRequire%20all%20granted%E2%80%9D](https://www.budgetvm.com/kb/client-denied-by-server-configuration/#:%7E:text=To%20fix%20%E2%80%9Cclient%20denied%20by,replaced%20by%20%E2%80%9CRequire%20all%20granted%E2%80%9D)